# Koszul complex: isomorphism between $K(a_1,\ldots, a_n;A) \simeq K(a_1;A) \otimes \cdots \otimes K(a_n;A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Given $a_1,\dots,a_n\in A$, with $A$ a suitable ring, my algebra teacher defined the *Koszul complex associated to $a_1,\dots,a_n$ with coefficients in $A$* in this way: 
$$K(a_1,\dots,a_n;A):=\bigoplus_{i=0}^n\bigwedge^iA^n,$$
with differential $\partial$ such that $\partial(e_i)=a_i$.
With the rule
$$\partial(uv)=\partial(u)v+(-1)^iu\partial(v)$$if $u\in K(a_1,\dots,a_n;A)_i$, the Koszul complex is a DG-algebra. But if we consider the restriction of $\partial$ to $K(a_1,\dots,a_n;A)_i$ we obtain differentials $\partial_i$ for a chain complex.

I have to prove that the following isomorphism holds
$$K(a_1,\dots,a_n;A)\simeq K(a_1;A)\otimes\dots\otimes K(a_n;A).$$

This is clear "algebraically", but I need to find an isomorphism **of complexes**. Could you please help me?

Have a nice day.

Asdrubale

Comment: In the definition, it should be $\bigoplus\limits_{i=0}^n$.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase this is clear "algebraically"?